# regex work on Regex101 but doesn't work on bash

Tags: linux, bash, hook

I'm setting a hook and i need to evaluate a regex, but i don't know why is not working the regex in bash, i check a format in commit-msg

```
MSG = "$1"
FEAT='(feat)(\:\sRQ)([0-9])+(_)(([A-Z][a-z]+)+)'
if [[ MSG =~ TEST ]]  ; then      
   echo "yeah!!"
else            
echo "oops"
exit 1
fi
```

this is a valid commit message feat: RQ00_Hello

Comment: What does the input actually look like?

Comment: MSG is the commit message, i did git commit -m "feat: RQ00_Hello"

Comment: @xra, configure "Regex101" or whatever you're testing against for POSIX ERE syntax. Bash uses the standard C library for regex matching, so if your local platform has extensions you'll sometimes get non-portable, local-OS-only extra features, but the only thing that's guaranteed to work is the minimal set of features specified in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html, section 9.4 ("Extended Regular Expressions").

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that `\:` is unnecessary, and believe that bash doesn't understand `\s`.

P.S.: Btw, you also need to lose the SPACES around the `=` in the first line... the variables in the test are missing `$`, and $TEST != $FEAT

Comment: bash *definitely* isn't guaranteed to understand anything but POSIX ERE, and `\s` is not part of that spec.